# Why exactly elements in different Sylow subgroups can't commute in $A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

My professor remarked that:

> There is no room in $A_5$ for anything to commute.
>   Or certainly not for elements in different Sylows to commute.

Can someone please explain why "there is no room" in $A_5$ for elements in different Sylow subgroups to commute? Does it have to do anything with the fact that $A_5$ is simple?

Comment: In some sense, there's no "room" for an element of order $5$ and an element of order $3$ to commute, since their product would have order $15$, but the smallest symmetric group with an element of order $15$ is $S_8$, not $S_5$.

Answer (score 5):

In $A_5$, there's no "room" for anything to commute, in the sense that, for any $\sigma,\tau$ in different Sylow subgroups, they can't consist of disjoint cycles.

There are only five elements to permute, and everything is a product of at least two transpositions, which necessarily involves three of those five elements.

But when different transpositions are not disjoint, as $(12)$ and $(13)$, they  don't commute.

Since the $3$-Sylow and $5$-Sylow subgroups consist in $3$-cycles and $5$-cycles, and the $2$-Sylow subgroups consist in products of two transpositions, one can try to argue along those lines.

Comment: What are $\sigma$ and $\tau$?

Comment: You say permutations cannot commute because they cannot be disjoint, but disjointness is not a necessary condition for commutativity. For example, $(1\;2)(3\;4)$ and $(1\;3)(2\;4)$ commute.

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  @MikeEarnest

Comment: They only claimed that elements that in different Sylow subgroups can commute. In $A_5$, the Sylow subgroups are made up of $5$-cycles, so the explanation only needs to apply to $5$-cycles. I myself am not sure if the professor is saying anything which can be made precise.

Comment: @MikeEarnest The claim is that elements in different Sylow subgroups *can't* commute

Comment: @MikeEarnest The claim is precise: if $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow subgroups of $A_5$ with $P \ne Q$, $\sigma \in P \setminus \{1\}$ and $\tau \in Q \setminus \{ 1\}$, then $\sigma\tau \ne \tau \sigma$. The argument in this answer works except when $P$ and $Q$ are distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups. In that case, you could argue that all elements of $P \setminus \{1\}$ fix exactly one point, and all elements of $Q \setminus \{1\}$ fix a different point, for example $\sigma = (2,3)(4,5)$ and $\tau = (1,3)(2,4)$. But if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commute then $\sigma$ permutes Fix$(\tau)$, contradiction.